# jquery reconstructing a selector from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, css-selectors

I am taking the value of a select element and trying to modify it so that I can have access to the onscreen preview element that the select item represents. Here is the first part of the code...

```
$("#single_area_select").change(function(){
        var $element = '#preview_' + $("#single_area_select").val().toLowerCase();
        elementChangedOrSelected($element);
    });
```

And the critical part of the elementChangedOrSelected() method...

```
function elementChangedOrSelected(element){
    element = '$("' + element + '")';
    alert(element);
    var position = element.position();
    alert(position);
```

My first alert makes it look like i've got it right (ie, $("#preview_title") ), but the second alert doesn't make an appearance which tells me that the position query is failing. Can anyone see something that I can't?

Comment: Using alerts is a lousy way to debug Javascript. For all the major browsers (read: Firefox, Safari, IE8, Opera) there are good debuggers. Firefox's is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com); Safari, IE8, and Opera have them built-in. Happy debugging!

Comment: i work primarily with Chrome, but you're right and thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function elementChangedOrSelected(element){
    element = $(element);
    alert(element);
    var position = element.position();
    alert("left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this.  `'$("' + element + '")'` returns a string, which would not have a position method.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do this:

```
position = $(element).position();
```